# Error in mathematical symbols in "Article" document class

Tags: symbols, article

When I use the mathematical symbols, with an error, the compiler stops. for example for `\leq` or `\mu`. What is the reason and solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please remember that in order to use greek mathematical symbols you need to be in a math environment given either by:

```
$\mu$
```

or

```
\[ \mu \]
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
\mu
\end{equation}
```